# pandas: does the groupby object store the index?

Tags: python, pandas

From what I understand, `groupby` requires computing an index on the grouped variables. However, I'm not entirely sure if that is stored in the groupby object.

My code looks like

```
df.groupby(["col1","col2"]).agg( something )
( ... some code ... )
df.groupby(["col1","col2"]).agg( something else )
```

Am I correct in understanding that the following would avoid the index being built twice?

```
my_group = groupby(["col1","col2"])
my_group.agg( something )
( ... some code ... )
my_group.agg( something else )
```

This matters to me because I'm writing something that has to pass over the groups twice, and if the index is not stored I might have to implement my own `groupby`.

Comment: Can you give a little more context? Is the worry that it takes a lot of time to form the groups, so you’d only like to do it once? Or do you need to use the results of your first aggregations in the second?

Answer (score 1):

yes groupby computes index for computing aggregations and it stores the index being built again if we can store it in groupby object

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
                         "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                    "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
                          "one", "one", "two", "two"],
                    "C": ["small", "large", "large", "small",
                          "small", "large", "small", "small",
                         "large"],
                    "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                    "E": [2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9]})
df4 = df3.sort_values(['A','B'])
res1 = df3.groupby(['A', 'B'])['D'].mean()
res2 = df4.groupby(['A', 'B'])['D'].median()

print res1.index
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'bar', u'foo'], [u'one', u'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=[u'A', u'B'])

print res2.index
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'bar', u'foo'], [u'one', u'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=[u'A', u'B'])
```

you can definitely do

```
my_group = df3.groupby(['A', 'B']) 
print type(my_group)
pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy
```

and then can perform different aggregation over the same groupby object created assuring it will not calculates the index again.

let me know if this helps

Comment: Your example provides no evidence that the index is saved as opposed to recomputed. My question was not "is an index calculated".